# Rails NoMethodError undefined method `data' for nil:NilClass (Controller#update)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, nomethoderror, updatemodel

**Edit: it turns out I made a very simple mistake and had a Template that was associated with a LocalTemplate id that no longer existed. If anyone has this problem and thinks that they somehow are unable to unable to associate the id of another model in their update action, make sure that you didn't accidentally delete the parent object causing that id to no longer exist!
The code below, while dramatically simplified did work for me.**

I have a Template model in my rails app. It has a method "data" defined in it.

I am able to access this method in the create and show actions with @template.data, however when using the same @template.data in the update action of my controller I get a no method error because I am not showing the correct local template id to it. This line can be found in the model where it reads `base_data = YAML.load(local_template.data)`

I stored an id of the associated local_template when initially saving a new template, but how can I make sure I reference that id again in the update action so I do not get a no method error?

Here is a simplified version of the Template model and controller

Model:

```
    class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
      def data
        base_data = YAML.load(local_template.data)
        # couldn't pass the correct LocalTemplate here because
        # the local_template_id I had in my Template model no
        # longer existed. Changing the id to a LocalTemplate
        # that did exist fixed the issue.
      end
    end
```

Controller:

```
    class TemplatesController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @business = Business.find(params[:business_id])
        @templates = @business.templates.all
      end

      def new
        @business = Business.find(params[:business_id])
        @local_templates = LocalTemplate.all
        @template = @business.templates.build
      end

      def create
        @business = Business.find(params[:business_id])
        @local_templates = LocalTemplate.all
        @template = @business.templates.build(template_params)

        if @template.save
          @template.data #works fine here

          redirect_to business_url(@template.business_id)
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def show
        @business = Business.find(params[:business_id])
        @template = @business.templates.find(params[:id])
        @template.data #works fine here too
      end

      def edit
        @business = Business.find(params[:business_id])
        @local_templates = LocalTemplate.all
        @template = @business.templates.find(params[:id])
      end

      def update
       @business = Business.find(params[:business_id])
       @template = @business.templates.find(params[:id])

        if @template.update_attributes!(pass_template_params)

          Api.new.update_template(@template.data.to_json) #this is where I had a problem

          redirect_to business_url(@template.business_id)
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: I'm having real trouble reconciling `@template.update_attributes(template_params)` with `@template.data #can't use it here or I get a no method error` have you overridden `update_attributes` in `Template`?

Comment: I removed a lot of code in an attempt to make things clear, but after `if @template.update_attributes(template_params)` I make an API call that needs to use @template.data. I'm not showing the call, but that is where it would go and it doesn't work.

Comment: After that line is something like: `Api.new.update_template(@template.data)`

Comment: Right, but if `if @template.update_attributes(template_params)` is satisfied, it can't be nil. Which makes the error (which indicates that it is nil), very confusing. Have you removed additional code in that method? It might be worth replacing it, and maybe including your stack trace. Does it refer to `argument.data` instead of `argument` in `Api.new.update_template`?

Comment: Brad you are right, I wasn't looking close enough. The problem is actually inside the data method of the Template model. I will update the code to reflect this.

Comment: @BradWerth The issue is with this line in the model `base_data = YAML.load(local_template.data)` In the create action I am saving an id of the local_template that will be associated with the template. How should I reference this so that it works for the update action?

Comment: This is probably worth making a new (dramatically simplified) question, or editing this one to illustrate your issue. FWIW, I would consider adding the id that you need to pass around as a hidden field in the form. Take this with a grain of salt, as I am only guessing.

Comment: Thanks @BradWerth. I will take a moment to look into it more myself and will update the question if I cannot figure it out. Yes, the id is a hidden field in the form. It is for the user to select from a set of preset templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing a lot. There is a lot to refactor in your controller...
First of all, your TemplatesController should be about the template resources, but your controller looks more like a BusinessesController. In general your update action for example should look more like:

```
def update
  @template = Template.find params[:id]
  @template.attributes = template_params # though this should raise a NoMethodError, because you dind't define it; I'd prefer params[:template] if possible
  if @template.save
    redirect_to business_url(@template.business_id)
  else
    @local_templates = LocalTemplate.all
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Instantiating @business and @local_templates makes non sense, because you don't use it at all. Speed up your responses if you can! :)
Fixed that, there is no need for the overhead of a nested resource in update (as you did).
If saving @template fails for validation reasons, you better should load the business object late by:

```
@template.business
```

in your /templates/edit.html.erb partial. Then you also do not need a nested route to your edit action... You see, it cleans up a lot.
As a general guideline you should create as less as possible controller instance variables.
If you cleaned up your controller and views, debugging your data issue will be easier.
I assume:

```
local_template
```

in your Template model to be an associated LocalTemplate model object. So it should no issue to call that anywhere if you ensured the referenced object exists:

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  def data
    return if local_template.nil?
    YAML.load(local_template.data)
  end
end
```

or validate the existence of the local_template object. or even b

Comment: Thanks @tobago my code example was dramatically simplified to show only what I believed to be immediately related to the problem. There is a lot more complexity going on in the actual controller. Templates belong to businesses and are edited from a specific businesses view. You are correct though and I made a simple mistake of having a Template that belonged to a LocalTemplate that no longer existed. I had to give it a new LocalTemplate id and then my update action worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm @template is not nil, if @template is nil, you can't use data method.

```
1.9.3-p547 :024 > nil.data
NoMethodError: undefined method `data' for nil:NilClass
from (irb):24
from /Users/tap4fun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

And you should use **update_attributes!**, it can raise an exception if record is invalid.

You can do like this.

```
if @template
   @template.update_attributes!(template_params)
   @template.data 
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that the issue is actually inside this line in the model `base_data = YAML.load(local_template.data)` and updated my question. I'm still not sure of the exact solution. I will use update_attributes! instead though; thanks for pointing that out.